# Telegram - Counting messages

Tags: debugging, logging, count, telegram

I'd like to count the messages of a specific conversation in Telegram. There should be a way using Telegram Desktop and using the debugmode to save the log information (see https://telegram.wiki/desktop/tdesktopcountingmessages). Unfortunately the *count*-tag is missing in most cases. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please open issue instead of asking here.

Comment: Problem already solved. In case someone else is looking for a message count, this chrome extension shows it:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-telegram-chat-histor/kgldnbjoeinkkgpphaaljlfhfdbndfjc

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way to do this currently is by searching for '+' in the conversation of interest. This will retrieve all messages and you can see the count from the search results. See attached image for an example. This conversation contains 32 messages in total.[image]